# How do I skip cutscenes in Need for Speed: The Run?

Tags: need-for-speed-the-run

I'm doing a second playthrough of story mode in Need for Speed: The Run, but I can't seem to figure out how to skip cutscenes.  Is there something I'm missing, or is this yet another feature they've not included?

Comment: @StephenVascellaro, again, these superfluous edits are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to skip cutscenes in [this game](http://www.next-gen.biz/reviews/need-speed-run-review):

> Stuffed with a procession of long-winded loading sequences, protracted menu flipping and unskippable cutscenes, it often feels like there’s as much watching  as there is playing.

Comment: Horribly disappointing, as is much of the rest of the game.  I'm really considering trading this in, which as a general rule I *don't* do.  Still, I'm having a hard time convincing myself that it was worth paying full price for.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(